# Sleeping for certain numbers lasts forever in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, floating-point, sleep

I'm writing a bash script in Ubuntu 13.04 that requires to *sleep* a specific number of seconds passed by parameter.
I've made sure that *sleep* allows floating point numbers looking in the documentation:

> Unlike most  implementations  that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.

Indeed it works for certain values. For example it's ok for "0.1", "0.01", "0.02", "0.03" or "0.4" but it lasts forever for others values like "0.04" or "0.05".

I mean,
this will work:

```
sleep 0.03
```

... but this will last forever:

```
sleep 0.04
```

Anybody knows why?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you use "env sleep" instead of "sleep" ?

Comment: Have you invoked another terminal and run top and ps to see what's going on? You might also want to put this up in launchpad as a possible Ubuntu bug or a question. I've tried this on 12.04, and sleep 0.04 works. So, this may be a bug in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not reproducible here, any value I throw at `sleep` works as intended.

Comment: env sleep hangs too.
I've tried it in 12.10 and it works, indeed it looks like a 13.04 bug

Comment: I've just tried it in another machine with 13.04 and it works in there. Now I can't guess what the problem is...

Comment: Try running `strace sleep 0.04`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug with sleep command...

You can alternatively use bash implementation until that bug is fixed, create this alias on your script, but see `sleep --help` if you want to simulate all features.

```
alias sleep='read -t'
```

now try it:

```
date +"%S.%N"; sleep 0.04; date +"%S.%N";
```

this works on ubuntu 12.10 already.

EDIT: this is less precise but works too if you dont need the extra functionalities of sleep command:

```
function FUNCsleep() { 
  local delay=$1;
  local beginAt=`date +"%s.%N"`;
  while true; do 
    local now=`date +"%s.%N"`;
    if((`echo "($now-$beginAt)>=$delay" |bc -l`==1));then 
      break;
    fi;
  done;
}
alias sleep='FUNCsleep'
```

Comment: @user1031431 as you said on your comment that it works on another 13.10 machine, you should check the `sleep --version` (mine is 8.13). Other than that possible difference, my guess would be you have faulty hardware. But as 3 ppl (til now) voted up your question, I could also think on a faulty cpu version, but that may be too much guessing...